# Regex for word between symbols

Tags: regex, boundary

Does someone knows how to make a regex that looks for a word between two instances of the same symbol?

For example, in `"gaag a gaga $fafaga$afa"`, I need "fafaga", between the two "$" symbols.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use following regex if you just want one match :

```
\$[^$]*\$
```

*Note*: this will works for all matches if you use modifier `g` to make it global.

[see the Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE0wP4/2)

and following for all matches :

```
\$.*?\$
```

And if you don't want `$` you can use capture grouping and return the group after match :

```
\$([^$]*)\$
```

Comment: Tnx, is working, i must find only how to remove "$" symbols :)

Comment: @АлександърКастелиев For that you need to use capture grouping. and then get the first group after match or as in another answer you can use look around

Answer (score 0):

> I need "fafaga", between the two "$" symbols

You can use lookahead and lookbehind for extracting exactly the content between `$`'s

```
(?<=\$)([^$]*)(?=\$)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/6)

**Note:** lookbehinds are not supported by all regex engines

Comment: This is working, tnx. But there is a problem. If i have another "$" in the text, it takes and the next word between them like "gv 
$
Rp
e
uT
o
$ ef
   f''j$gg
it?
burp

Comment: You can use `\$(.*?)\$` and get `$1` (group 1)